# How to convert from SVN to HG when the Repo has no trunk/branches/tags structure at all?

Tags: svn, mercurial, migration

I have a SVN repo with no trunk/branches/tags structure at all (not good, I know...), so all projects are directly located in the Repo.
When I try hg convert, it says 
`file:///c/MySvnRepo does not look like a Subversion repository`

I have tried to create the trunk/branches/tags folders and move all content to the trunk. Then I got a HG repo with the structure I expect, but its history starts with the revision where I moved the content to the trunk.

I also tried the option `--config convert.svn.trunk=xy`, where xy was either a blank or any of the contained projects. It still aborted saying "...doesn't look like..."

I'm on Windows 7 64bit, SVN 1.7.2, Mercurial 1.9.3

I have found a lot of questions dealing with more complex structures, but none for this simple structure. Maybe the answer is so simple that I can't see it.

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add hgsubversion extension and clone any part of repository, using corresponding URL.

Never tried with file:// protocol, but can't see reasons for different behavior, than svn|http

**Sample**

```
z:\>dir /B
svn-repo
hg-repo
wc
```

---

```
z:\>svn ls -v file:///Z:/svn-repo
      3 Badger                окт 20 01:47 ./
      3 Badger             42 окт 20 01:47 data.txt
```

---

```
z:\>hg help subversion
Working with Subversion Repositories
...
```

---

```
z:\>hg clone --verbose -- file:///Z:/svn-repo Z:\hg-repo
using single layout
[r1] Badger: Ininial data
A data.txt
substituting author "Badger" for default "Badger@7b881c4c-2bda-1f48-a8b3-d2b14f06ee49"
data.txt
 committed to "default" as 7965fdc9055d
[r2] Badger: Change 1
M data.txt
data.txt
 committed to "default" as c266778f29c0
[r3] Badger: Add-on
M data.txt
data.txt
 committed to "default" as 2aa45237e3b3
pulled 3 revisions
updating to branch default
resolving manifests
getting data.txt
1 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
```

---

```
z:\>cd hg-repo

z:\hg-repo>hg log
changeset:   2:2aa45237e3b3
tag:         tip
user:        Badger@7b881c4c-2bda-1f48-a8b3-d2b14f06ee49
date:        Fri Oct 19 19:47:54 2012 +0000
summary:     Add-on

changeset:   1:c266778f29c0
user:        Badger@7b881c4c-2bda-1f48-a8b3-d2b14f06ee49
date:        Fri Oct 19 19:47:00 2012 +0000
summary:     Change 1

changeset:   0:7965fdc9055d
user:        Badger@7b881c4c-2bda-1f48-a8b3-d2b14f06ee49
date:        Fri Oct 19 19:46:09 2012 +0000
summary:     Ininial data
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm afraid I can't get hgsubversion to work. When I read about installing Python bindings and so on I gave up, as I'm a windows dummy. I think I'll preserve history until now in the old SVN repo and start with a new HG repo.

Comment: @PeterStock - did you try to install and use hgsubversion? I have **WinXP box** for games with Tortoise(SVN|HG) only (no Python, no any special "binding"), but hgsubversion **works** long time, without remarkable glitches

Comment: Yes, I tried. Maybe it's a different problem. I typed `hg convert c:\Path\to\svn\repo\project1 c:\HG\Project1` (I've seen this somewhere) and got the message `abort: repository c:\Path\to\svn\repo\project1 not found!`. I thought that the hgsubversion extension were not working.

Comment: @PeterStock - it's only convert, not hgsubversion. With hgsubversion you clone svn-repo using `hg clone` and have to add extension manually. Try it, even with "file:///" protocol

Comment: Same result! I also tried it only using the Path to the Repo `c:\Path\to\svn\repo`. In TortoiseHG's global settings, hgsubversion is checked, so it seems to be installed. Thanks for your patient help, Lazy Badger! I hope you have another idea.